# How to submit form on open of HTML

Tags: html, forms, submit

I have a work computer server that requires and EmpID and then two passwords to login.  I can save the source of the login screen and then hard code the value=  for each of the fields with my information.(EmpID, Password1, Password2).  Opening this file and pressing the Login button works with my information in the value=. I'm just trying to stream line so I don't have to press the Login button and then I can use this file in an app I'm creating with Android App Inventor.

I would like this to submit when I open the file.  I don't want to have to press the login button.
Is there a way to change the

```
input type="submit" name="ctl01$mHolder$CmdLogin" value="      Login     " onclick=
```

to something that will submit on open of file instead of onclick?
Any suggestions?

Thanks!!!

Here is the HTML source from my work server.  I changed the address of the server and my EmpID and Passwords...

```
<html xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:w="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form name="aspnetForm" method="post" action="https://my.work.com/Default.aspx" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" id="aspnetForm"> 
<div> 
<input type="hidden" name="__LASTFOCUS" id="__LASTFOCUS" value="" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET".__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;         theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument; 
<div class="loginOuterStyle"> 
<div class="ie5borderfix">
<div class="formHeader">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="formContent"> 
<div class="contentHeader">&nbsp;</div>
<div class="contentArea"> 
<div class="validateErrorSummary">
<div id="ctl01_mHolder_validateErrorSummary" style="color:Red;display:none;">
</div> 
<form>
<table id="ctl01_mHolder_LoginTable" class="formTable"> 
<tr class="formHeader"> 
<td class="formCell"> 
<div class="empID">
<label>Login ID:</label>                 
<div class="inputItem">
<input name="ctl01$mHolder$txtUserID" type="text" maxlength="5" id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserID" VALUE="MyEmpID" class="inputField" size="15" /> 
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserIDRfValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserIDReValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
</div>
</div>             
<div class="coPassword">                 
<label>CO Password:</label>                    
<div class="inputItem">                     
<input name="ctl01$mHolder$txtUserESCPassword" type="password" maxlength="50" id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserESCPassword" VALUE="111111" class="inputField" size="15" />
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserESCPasswordRfValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>                     
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserESCPasswordReValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>                 
</div>
</div>             
<div class="ccsPassword">                 
<label>CCS Password:</label>                    
<div class="inputItem">                     
<input name="ctl01$mHolder$txtUserPassword" type="password" maxlength="8" id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserPassword" VALUE="222222" class="inputField" size="15" /> 
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserPasswordRfValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>  
<span id="ctl01_mHolder_txtUserPasswordReValidator" style="color:Red;display:none;"></span>
</div>
</div> 
<div class="contentSubmit">
<input type="submit" name="ctl01$mHolder$CmdLogin" value="      Login     " onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(&quot;ctl01$mHolder$CmdLogin&quot;, &quot;&quot;, true, &quot;LoginGroup&quot;, &quot;&quot;, false, false))" id="ctl01_mHolder_CmdLogin" />
</div>
<div class=WordSection1></form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please tidy your HTML up, it's currently unreadable.

Comment: Dai, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm learning, but slowly!!!  I hope this is better. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the jQuery on change method:

```
$('input[name=ctl01$mHolder$CmdLogin]').on("change", function(){ domysubmit(); });
```

or even native Javascript onchange method with little tweaking.

```
<input type='file' onchange='submitFile(this)'/>

function submitFile(el){
   var fn = $(el).val();//get file path
   domysubmit();
}
```

Comment: I'm trying your first answer in place of the "  input type="submit" name="ctl01$mHolder$CmdLogin" value="      Login     " onclick=   "  Is that correct? I tried with and without the $ sign. I still not having any luck.  I am not a code writer so this is way above my head and I am just guessing...  Thanks

Comment: Chibueze,  I have tried both ways and I really don't know where to put either of these.  Like I said I am just randomly trying and nothing has worked so far...  I cleaned up the html code above.  Can you suggest where to place your code?  Thanks.

Comment: Problem is that your html code doesn't have a file input, so it's difficult to figure out how to help you here.